# Analysing likert data

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate basic statistics in R (mean, sd, var) for a following data frame (numbers in this table are frequencies of responses):

```
Question Strongly disagree Disagree Don't know Agree Strongly agree
    A             1            1        15       4          25
    B             1            1        18       3          23
    C             0            0        19       1          26
```

How can I calculate what I mentioned above and also visualize this data?

Comment: summary(), mean(), sd(), var()?

Comment: I think this problem is trickier, because the data is already compiled in a `table`-type class, so `summary()` etc. don't make much sense here

Comment: Do a search with `sos::findFn("likert")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get summary statistics in this case is to make the strong assumption that the differences between the responses are all the same (e.g. that the difference between "Strongly disagree" and "Disagree" is the same as the difference between "Disagree" and "Don't know"). If you're willing to make that assumption, then you can compute the weighted means.

```
tt <- read.table(header=TRUE,textConnection("
 Question Strongly_disagree Disagree Dont_know Agree Strongly_agree
 A             1            1        15       4          25
 B             1            1        18       3          23
 C             0            0        19       1          26"))

 tt2 <- tt[,-1]  ## scores only
 ss <- sweep(tt2,MARGIN=2,FUN="*",1:5) ## weight by numeric equivalent
```

Mean values: calculate the *weighted* mean of the scores

```
 (meanvals <- rowSums(ss)/rowSums(tt2))
 ## [1] 4.108696 4.000000 4.152174
```

These correspond to choices equal to, or slightly more positive than, "Agree".

Alternatively you can use `apply(tt2,1,weighted.mean,x=1:5)`

Standard deviations:

```
 devs <- outer(-meanvals,1:5,"+")
 sqrt(rowSums(devs^2*tt2)/rowSums(tt2))
```

(you might want to divide by `rowSums(tt2)-1` to get sample standard deviations).

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (when you have sufficient reputation)